# How to extract a variable from html(Jinja2) to python for modify a variable?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

The situation is the next.

I have a variable got from input in the html(jinja2) but I need to export it to python for change a variable that is in my python file.

```
<input type="number" name="DateO"/>
<input type="number" name="DateT"/>
```

I want to take "DateO" and "DateT" for a python variable.

pdt: I'm using Django

Comment: you must use a form for this. Is this a website? What is the backend of it?

Comment: Yes it is a website based in Django, the python file that is Done the interactivity is "Views.py" you can see its content right here
https://gyazo.com/610e670f16b8cea75828481f521dee78